# Storing a variable name within a variable using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, variables

Is it possible to reference a variable/array using another variable in asp.net c#?
EG.

```
alfaromeo = new string[] {"lots of stuff"};
astonmartin = new string[] {"lots of stuff"};
audi = new string[] {"lots of stuff"};
bentley = new string[] {"lots of stuff"};
bmw = new string[] {"lots of stuff"};

etc

string targetArray = "audi";

for(int i=0; i<targetArray.Length; i++){
    // do stuff with tha array
}
```

There is a reason the arrays are all called different names and I'm not using a multi dimensional array to referance them.

Can this be done, or do I need to use some sort of look up array to reference them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `string targetArray = "audi";` is this a `String` or a `String[]` ?

Comment: A string. This would be where a just store the name of the array I want to use, unless you are seeing something a lot more logical than I. Which is very possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not local variables.

I'd rather put the stuff in a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
  { "alfaromeo", new string[] {"lots of stuff"} }
  // etc...
}
```

Or if you insist on variables, put them into fields of a class, and use reflection:

```
class Z {
  public static string[] alfaromeo = new string[] {"lots of stuff"};
}
// ...
typeof(Z).GetField("alfaromeo", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null);
```

Comment: Sorry to be so dim, but if I use a dictionary, how do I reference them once stored?

Comment: `dict["alfaeomeo"]`  The string becomes the key into the dictionary. Try [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) for some better help